# How can I load the real parts of an array of std::complex with SSE?

Tags: x86, sse, simd

I'm trying to load in a 128-bit register the real parts of the content of an array of `std::complex<float>` thanks to the `_mm_loadu_ps()` Intrinsic function.

```
__m128 data_block;

complex<float> a[4];
a[0] = complex<float>(1.0, 2.0);
a[1] = complex<float>(3.0, 4.0);
a[2] = complex<float>(5.0, 6.0);
a[3] = complex<float>(7.0, 8.0);

data_block = _mm_loadu_ps(&a[0].real());

float b[4];
_mm_storeu_ps(b, data_block);

cout << b[0] << " " << b[1] << " " << b[2] << " " << b[3] << endl;
```

And I get the output `1 2 3 4` instead of `1 3 5 7`. 
This is because the `_mm_loadu_ps()` function loads the 4 data after the address given as parameter.

I know I could use intermediate arrays but my question is :
Is there any Intrinsic function that allows to perform a load, and respectively a store, operation with an offset ? So I could give `sizeof(float)` as the offset and load only the real parts of my array and store them after treatment.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No - this is a "gather" operation which is only supported by AVX (not SSE), and is also very inefficient. You should organise your data more appropriately if you are serious about SIMD optimisation. If you really have to stick with this data layout then the best option would probably be to load two consecutive vectors and shuffle (permute) them to get all real parts in one (and imaginary parts in the other, if needed), e.g.

```
__m128 v0 = _mm_loadu_ps(&a[0].real());
__m128 v1 = _mm_loadu_ps(&a[2].real());
__m128 v_real = _mm_shuffle_ps(v0, v1, _MM_SHUFFLE(2, 0, 2, 0));
__m128 v_imag = _mm_shuffle_ps(v0, v1, _MM_SHUFFLE(3, 1, 3, 1));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed, I have to work with this data layout. I will use your option, it should be fine even though it will increase the number of load/store operations.

Comment: If you need the imaginary parts too then there is no increase in the number of loads, but yes, if you just need the real parts then there's a 2x penalty. Hopefully you're doing enough computation afterwards though to absorb this cost.

Comment: Back in 2010, I rewrote my FFT from `{real,imag}{real,imag}` to `{real,real}{imag,imag}`. Result: Instant 30% speedup from getting rid of all the shuffles. The whole SSE3 `addsub` thing was basically a complete joke. :)